# Visual Studio 2019 - C# app crash with variable = ".level"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a very weird problem with Visual Studio 2019, a C# WinForms project.

In a certain point I have a simple String variable:

```
String myVar = "";
```

When I run the app, it works. But if I write this:

```
String myVar = ".level";
```

the app crashes, saying I have no rights for copying the generated .exe file from the obj/Debug folder to the bin/Debug folder.

If I change the variable with something different, for example simply writing the same string but with the uppercase:

```
String myVar = ".Level";
```

the app gets back running perfectly! Do anyone knows why the ".level" string (and only if it's writteng exactly in this way) breaks the app?

Comment: The typical reason for this error message is that the process is still running. Make sure the application is not running before you start the build.

Comment: Already checked it, and it's not the problem I'm talking about. The problem occurs only when I type ".level", exactly in this way, inside a variable.

Comment: Try to set your variable to bad value ".level" close VS, open it and launch the app? Does the magic still works?

Comment: @StefanoTerrana, Try giving us full code and full error.  You need to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: @demonplus Yes, the app continues to not work. It's really curious!

Comment: @Jiale There's no particular source code. Just create a new C# Winform project and place String myVar = ".level" somewhere, in the point you prefer.

Comment: @StefanoTerrana I did what you said with my .net 4.8 framework winform application in 2019 and 2022. No problems occurred. Please try restarting.

Comment: Before writing .level, check if you can find your app in Processes in Task Manager

Comment: @demonplus yes, it appears. To better explain the situation, it's like my app, with ".level" written anywhere in the code, becomes some kind of virus or malicious application that is blocked by the operating system. As I remove that written, the app mysteriously returns to work correctly, instantly, without the need to recompile it, close VS, restart the PC and so on.

Comment: @StefanoTerrana ok then try to compile with this strange variable and check with antivirus software. It is really strange

Comment: ok, for my antivirus, the produced .exe becomes a trojan if I use a variable with ".level" string on it. I just installed VS2022 and this problem doesn't happen! In 20 years I do this job, that's the first time I see such a thing!

Answer (score 1):

According to the discussion, the problem is due to `antivirus` software.

The produced `.exe` becomes a `trojan` if you use a variable with `.level` string on it.

If anyone has a similar problem, try rebooting and check their `virus scanner.`

There are currently no issues with the `2022 version`.